# Bootstrap table header color only shows when cell is hovered over

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table that I want to render with coloured header that is always on (not just when you hover over the cell.

```
    <div class="container-fluid fieldcontain col-sm-6" >
            <table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed' >

                <thead >
                <tr>
                    <th class="bg-info text-white" scope="col">Tag</th>
                    <th class="bg-info text-white" scope="col">Value</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row">hello</td>
                    <td scope="row">william</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

    </div>
```

I have tried variations on this including a custom CSS head style like this,  but this also only fires when I hover over a header cell.

custom.css

```
    .table .thead-blue th {
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
        foreground-color: cornflowerblue;
    }
```

but whatever I do, when the page renders and your mouse is not hovered over the cell is grey.  When you hover over a header column the colour is triggered.

I want that header colour all the time - not just when I hover of the header cell.

I've looked at examples etc. - but can't see why my default is grey.  I thought it would do this all the time.

Can any one help please?

[image]

Stripped it right back - no grails site mesh or anything just two tables

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <%--<meta name="layout" content="main" />--%>
    <title>Bootstrap try out</title>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js'></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">
    <%--<div class="container-fluid col-sm-6" >--%>
    <div class="col-xs-4">

        <table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed ' >

            <thead >
            <tr>
                <th class="bg-info text-white" scope="col">Tag</th>
                <th class="bg-info text-white" scope="col">Value</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">hello</td>
                <td scope="row">william</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<p>now table with border</p>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <caption> Map table</caption> <!-- appears at bottom -->
            <thead class="alert alert-info">
            <tr >
                <th>tag</th>
                <th>value</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>hello</td>
                <td>there</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Peter</td>
                <td>Parker</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

The first table is defaulted to grey,

the second table now has coloured headers.

[image]

the first table tries to add class to   - no soap, the second version

i put the grails site mesh back in using main.gsp ub uncommenting the meta tag, and commenting the css links out (as they are the same in main.gsp)

as soon as you enable the site mesh - the rendering stops working correctly

[image]

so it looks like something in the grails site std site mesh/styles etc just makes things break

Answer (score 0):

No. It's working. Try the in here codes. Or, add your all code.

```css
   .table .thead-blue th {
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
        foreground-color: cornflowerblue;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid fieldcontain col-sm-6" >
            <table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed' >

                <thead >
                <tr>
                    <th class="bg-info text-white" scope="col">Tag</th>
                    <th class="bg-info text-white" scope="col">Value</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row">hello</td>
                    <td scope="row">william</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: Ok so weird - i'm doing this inside a grails v3 app and i have a horrible suspicion that some weird nonsense goes on the back that stops things working as expected .  git hub project is here  https://github.com/woodmawa/LCM-network-app

Comment: i'm not a natural fron end developer so i've tried to use the grails fields plugin/site mesh etc as it does so much - except where it doesnt.  One of these is render a map attribute so what ive doen is create an input tag and generate a dropright action to display a table of the map tag and values - hence this snippit.  but there seem to be other problems in places as well.

Comment: iy you want to run it - you can clone the project and build.  I've set up a controller with my 'test page' at localhost:8080/maintenanceAgreement/ldt/1 which is a stadalone 'hack page' to look at rendering but it trigger the views/layouts/main.gsp to pu the header/footer wrap on

Comment: where can I see html?

Comment: Hi - ive updated the screenshots in the PS on the original post.  I have done a plain page with no grails - two tables first doesnt chnage the head colours but the second does .  Then i route page via grails site mesh and it breaks the colours completly

Comment: if you look at the latest stripped down page here https://github.com/woodmawa/LCM-network-app/blob/master/grails-app/views/maintenanceAgreement/ldt.gsp

Comment: this is plain page with site mesh disabled.  first table no colour chnages for header.  second version does (as per screenshot above now).  Soon as grails site mesh is engaged - it all stops as per second diagram

Comment: sooo frustrating .  i'll keep experimenting and see which bit of main.gsp stops it working?  whilst i do that in plain html first table why doesnt the header change colour ?

Comment: just added a third table but declared thead like this '           <thead class="thead-blue">'   and custom css like this '
.thead thead-blue  thead {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    foreground-color: cornflowerblue;
}

Comment: I don't understand :/

Comment: can you see the plain html page at https://github.com/woodmawa/LCM-network-app/blob/master/grails-app/views/maintenanceAgreement/ldt.gsp?

Comment: if so  cut and paste into you local place at render the page - you should see two tables - first with grey headers - the second now with coloured headers

Comment: ps just saved to git again with a third table where i tried to do custom style for headers - that doesnt work either.

Comment: I contributed to the project. Can you look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188117/discussion-between-william-woodman-and-dogukan-cavus).

Answer (score 0):

I tried a brute force approach, on both the CSS and Jscript and covered/uncovered each until something broke the Bootstrap.  This turns out to be in Grails' main.css. Then I went through the sections of the CSS and nailed it down to this

```
th {
    background-color: #efefef;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #eaeaea);
    /*background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #eaeaea));*/
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr = '#ffffff', EndColorStr = '#eaeaea');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ffffff', EndColorStr='#eaeaea')";
    color: #666666;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
}
```

I then went through each line in turn to test what works and doesn't - and it's down to one line of CSS!

The offending line is

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #eaeaea));
```

If you comment that out (I don't know what it is or does) all of a sudden your Bootstrap starts to behave as it would in a stand-alone page.

So I still have some issues with colouring table headers in Bootstrap - but that can wait.

For any one who wants to see the latest position on Github:

[project](https://github.com/woodmawa/LCM-network-app)

Latest changes:

1) copied main.gsp to lcm-main and edited that so I could track what I was changing in layout.gsp 
2) changed controller page's meta tag to use the lcm-main template 
3) wasn't sure what was going on at one stage on Bootstrap - so i've installed latest CSS, stylesheets into assets and changed the application.js and application.css to pick up the latest Bootstrap 4.2.1

Tables are now rendering as I was expecting and headers can be made to go some colour.

So lcm-main.gsp looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html  >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <title>
        <g:layoutTitle default="LCM Inventory"/>
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <asset:stylesheet src="lcm-application.css"/>
    <%--<g:external  file="lcm-app.css" />--%> <%--this works and knows default place for stylesheets --%>


    <!--<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <%--<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>--%>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />

    <%--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    --%>

    <g:layoutHead/>

    <%-- header assets --%>

</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/#"><asset:image src="inventoryDisksImage.png" width="7%" height="6%" alt="LCM Logo" /></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0.8px;" id="navbarContent">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <g:pageProperty name="page.nav"/>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>


<g:layoutBody />

<div class="footer row" role="contentinfo" class="container-fluid">
    <p>LCM Footer version x.y</p>

</div>


<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
    <g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/>
</div>

<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Now my controller page and the standalone page (no site mesh) seem to both behave the same way.

The revised application.js now looks this

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js.
//
// Any JavaScript file within this directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// You're free to add application-wide JavaScript to this file, but it's generally better
// to create separate JavaScript files as needed.
//= require popper.min
//= require bootstrap.4.2.1/bootstrap
//= require jquery-3.3.1.min
//= require LCM-app
//= require_self
```

and the application.css looks like this

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS file within this directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
* compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*
*= require bootstrap.4.2.1
*= require grails
*= require main
*= require mobile
*= require lcm-app
*= require_self
*/
```

So finally I'm going to raise a bug and see if I can save any one 4 days of pain to get this far.